# ffmpeg 3D conversion - EAC stereo (Youtube) to Equirectangular stereo?

Tags: ffmpeg, video, video-conversion, youtube, 3d

I've had success with converting monoscopic equiangular cube maps (EAC) videos, but I can't get the filters to work for stereoscopic.  There's an example in the ffmpeg manual in the v360 filter section that seems to address this scenario:

> Convert transposed and horizontally flipped Equi-Angular Cubemap in
> side-by-side stereo format to equirectangular top-bottom stereo
> format:
> `v360=eac:equirect:in_stereo=sbs:in_trans=1:ih_flip=1:out_stereo=tb`

But this doesn't work (see the image below).  The result I get seems scrambled.  Anyone an expert in these filters?  Is there a way to apply other filters to each eye independently, or another work around?

Applying the v360 filter for rotated EAC SBS doesn't convert correctly to ER TB:

[image: Applying the v360 filter for rotated EAC SBS doesn't convert correctly to ER TB]

Answer (score 2):

OK, this seems to work.  Rotate the whole video clockwise with the transpose filter first, then apply the v360 filters:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "transpose=1,v360=eac:e:in_stereo=tb:out_stereo=tb" output.mp4
```

Adding these additional scale and ratio filters seems to produce decent results for the final video.  I'm unsure if the generation loss is down to a minimum, as I haven't extensively tested this.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "transpose=1,v360=eac:e:in_stereo=tb:out_stereo=tb,scale=ih:ih,setsar=sar=1,setdar=dar=h/h" output.mp4
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).